# timediff with three columns/parameters

Tags: mysql

I have three timestamp columns which have different time stamp values.
I want to calculate the time difference,but the time difference takes only 2 parameters and i have three.

```
 select date_format(timediff(t1,t2),'%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds ago') as    
 time_spent1,date_format(timediff(t3,timediff(t2,t1)), 
'%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds ago') as time_spent2
 from timer_test where key_val=1;
```

In results for time_spent2 it shows null.How do i calculate time difference for 3 columns

Comment: What are your expected results? How do you calculate the difference between tree values?

Comment: So the first timestamp tells me the time when a ticket was raised,the second tells me when the ticket was open and third tells me when the ticket was closed.
So i want to calculate the total time it took for the ticket to get resolved ie closed

Comment: A time difference is between 2 times... by definition. You do not seem to know exactly what you want. By your comment I expect all you need is the difference between raised and closed. What does the open time tell you? What are you not explaining to us? Are there NULLs somewhere? Can a ticket be opened without it being raised? You should elaborate a bit, if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, you can use the `IFNULL` function to calculate the difference with `t2` or `t3` depending on if  `t3` has a value or not:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(t1,IFNULL(t3,t2)),'%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds ago') 
  FROM timer_test 
 WHERE key_val=1;
```